# Lambda Apply to find difference between two dates

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use apply method with lambda to find the months between two dates. I'm currently getting a attribute error:

> AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'dt'

My upfront conversion:

```
df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1'], errors='ignore', infer_datetime_format=True)
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2'], errors='ignore', infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Here is my block:

```
df['Duration (Months)'] = df.apply(lambda x: x["Date1"].dt.to_period('M').astype(int) - x["Date2"].dt.to_period('M').astype(int), axis=1)
```

Second attempt:

```
df['Duration (Months)'] = df['date1'].dt.to_period('M').astype(int) - df['date2'].dt.to_period('M').astype(int)
```

Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: When you use `apply` with `axis=1`, you apply the function to the rows, instead of columns. Therefore, your selection becomes one item on a row, which has the type `datetime.date`. [See](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). `.dt` is  applied to columns (pd.Series).

Comment: You have the Python's datetime's date in the column. You probably need to convert both `Date1` and `Date2` to `pd.to_datetime` and do not use `apply` just do `df['Duration (Months)'] = df['Date1'].dt.to_period('M').astype(int) - df['Date2'].dt.to_period('M').astype(int)` instead.

Comment: @Emma I do the conversion beforehand. I also did take a stab at applying to the whole column (see edit).

Comment: still same error?  could you check `df.dtypes` and what datatype do you have for those columns?

Comment: @Emma it was a typo in my actual column name haha. It's working now, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#dt-accessor) :

> **Series** has an **accessor** to succinctly **return datetime** like properties
> for the values of the Series, if it is a datetime/period like Series.
> This will return a Series, indexed like the existing Series.

So there is no need to use the [`.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#dt-accessor) accessor when calling [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html?highlight=pandas%20series%20apply#pandas.Series.apply) because this one access to each element (that is already a `datetime`) individually. Hence the errors below (depending on the type of your Series) :

```
AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'dt'
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'dt'
```

Try this instead :

```
(df.apply(lambda x: x["date1"].to_period('M') - x["date2"].to_period('M'), axis=1))
```

Or with a vectorial code :

```
(df["date1"].dt.to_period('M') - df["date2"].dt.to_period("M")) #here, we needed the .dt accessor

0    <0 * MonthEnds>
1    <-1 * MonthEnd>
2    <6 * MonthEnds>
dtype: object
```

This will return a [`pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html?highlight=dateoffset#pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset). Therefore to cast a number/int, you can use [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) to get the name as an attribute :

```
from operator import attrgetter

(df["date1"].dt.to_period('M') - df["date2"].dt.to_period("M")).apply(attrgetter("n"))

0    0
1   -1
2    6
dtype: int64
```

*Used input :*

```
       date1      date2
0 2022-01-13 2022-01-01
1 2022-02-05 2022-03-06
2 2022-10-14 2022-04-09

date1    datetime64[ns]
date2    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```